# How to integrate parse with phonegap

Tags: android, database, cordova, parse-platform

I want to developed an app for cross mobile platform (iOS / Andriod). I am using phonegap and parse for the same.

Super admin will upload the content of the app for particular user from the website, which will update or fired the parse database server.

Once user login in the application, he/she can access the same file uploaded by admin in the web. We are using parse database for the same.

Is it possible to access the database of parse.com from web ?? Since admin can upload the data to parse.com from webpage ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using PG and parse.com I guess you are also using the javascrip API of Parse.com

Just use it the same way from the web or I am missing something from the question?

Comment: Actually is there any way to access the parse's database from phonegap? if yes then how? @Arcayne

Answer (score 0):

You need phonegap to deal with the device not your backend.

Get famliar with https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide, you will also need something like

https://github.com/ericterpstra/ngSignIt

Care about Phonegap when taking a pic, checking you online staus . . . this kind of thing.